# Cannot make use of a .jar file if it has more than one thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jar

When I create a .jar file and the program only uses the main thread then everything is fine but when I need concurrency and add my own thread the .jar file does not open or run one I double click it.

Here is an Example:

```
class idk {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame j = new JFrame();
                    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    j.setVisible(true);

                    j.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500);
                    j.pack();
                    j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                } catch(Exception e1) {}
            }
        }).start();
     }
}
```

The above code will not execute for some reason when compiled into a .jar file.
However if I just used the same code but left out the thread it works just fine.

Comment: Have you copy-pasted your code exactly? It has a syntax error and cannot be compiled. How do you create jar-file (some build system / export in IDE / jar util)?

Answer (score 0):

You must only ever use one thread, Swing's event dispatching thread (EDT), to interact with UI components.  Create your main window with this code:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { ... } );
```

Concurrency in the application should be done using the `SwingWorker` objects, and the `publish` method, if they need to interact with the UI.

Creating your own `Thread`s and creating or using Swing components from those threads will cause you grief.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)